# Howto remove duplicates in perl array of hashes based on one unique key and concatenate others

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Can someone help me with a Perl code snippet to convert from:

Note: ipn must be the unique key

```
@part = (
{
   ipn       => "12345",
   ticket_id => "10",
},
{
   ipn       => "12346",
   ticket_id => "11",
},
{
   ipn  => "12345",
   ticket_id => "12",
},
);
```

to:

```
@part_new = (
{
   ipn       => "12345",
   ticket_id => "10, 12",
},
{
   ipn       => "12346",
   ticket_id => "11",
},
);
```

Any other alternative solution to achieve something similar is also very welcome. The end result is to know which "ticket numbers" are associated with each unique part number (ipn).

Thank you.

Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a hash to keep track of which ticket_ids go with which ipns.
The keys of the subhash keyed off of the ticket_id will have all of the matching ipns.  Later we can merge them together to produce a new array of hash references.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @parts = (
    { ipn => "12345", ticket_id => "10", },
    { ipn => "12346", ticket_id => "11", },
    { ipn => "12345", ticket_id => "12", },
);

my %ipns;
for my $part ( @parts ) {
    # Keep track of which ticket_ids go with each ipn
    # 12345 -> 10
    #       -> 12
    # 12346 -> 11
    $ipns{ $part->{ipn} }->{ $part->{ticket_id} }++;
}

my @grouped_parts;
for my $ipn ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %ipns ) {
    my @tickets = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $ipns{ $ipn } };
    # Merge the ticket ids with each ipn
    push @grouped_parts, {
        ipn => $ipn,
        ticket_ids => join(', ', sort { $a <=> $b } @tickets)
    }; 
}

print Dumper(@grouped_parts);
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ipn' => '12345',
          'ticket_ids' => '10, 12'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'ipn' => '12346',
          'ticket_ids' => '11'
        };
```